# MVVM - WPF Desktop

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view

Just started learning MVVM. I have a tabcontrol where I am adding multiple instances of same views/pages

```
    Dim tb As New UXTabItem

    tb.Header = "Childrens"

    tb.Name = "tab" & itrt
    itrt = itrt + 1

    tb.Source = New Uri("/Views/childrens.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
UXTabControl1.Items.Add(tb)
```

Since each of the same view will handle different data but since the uri is same so all the tabs get populated with same view and changes reflect on each tabs. Which should not be the case. Should I be using a separate viewmodel for each of those? Any example would be much helpful.

Comment: Although this is a 3rd party component I thought UXTabItem.Source property is mostly used for static XAML contents such as customer info, contact us info etc? Are you trying to achieve explicit instances of "childrens" then you must host them as UserControls. Also the source property has no knowledge of the underlying ViewModel of the View plus even its code behind chidlrens.xaml.cs (as it wont be including that for UI creation of "childrens")...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the primary goals/advantages of MVVM is that you don't create WPF UI objects in code.

You should be populating a collection of view model objects and binding the `ItemsSource` of the `TabControl` that you define in XAML to it.  You should have a `DataTemplate` defined for the data type of those objects and put their XAML in there, instead of loading it at runtime.

The `TabControl` is a little tricky, because it uses *two* templates:  the `ItemTemplate` is used to define the look of the tab, and the `ContentTemplate` is used to define the look of the tab items' content.  It's pretty common to see this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
   <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
   <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

which populates the tab with a `Text` property on the view model, and the tab item's content with whatever template in the resource dictionary matches the view model's type.

Answer (score 2):

I would have an `ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Tabs` in my parent ViewModel, and bind the TabControl's ItemSource to that. Each Tab has it's own instance of TabViewModel, so adding a new Tab would mean adding a new `TabViewModel` to the `Tabs` collection in the ParentViewModel.

The TabViewModel would contain properties for things like `Header` or `Uri`, and these would be bound to the UI at the appropriate spots. Each TabViewModel can be drawn using the same View, but the data inside the object would be different for each tab.

My ParentViewModel would also contain a `TabIndex` property that defines which tab is selected

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT trivial, IMO, and Rachel and Robert are both right.

Think of this task being one of managing 'work spaces", each represented by a tab control. I like to structure my view models into three related layers

1. DetailViewModel - the model for a given workspace (represented by a tab control)
2. MasterViewModel - the model for a collection of detail view models (ObservableCollection{DetailViewModel}). You would use this to bind to a list ion our presentation that shows what items may be selected for editing  / display in a tab control. This is where filtering of the list would also be handled, if you allow that.
3. ShellViewModel - the model that actually has a collection of workspaces (ie, ObservableCollection{Workspace} along with the commands to manage them (ie, EditWorkspaceCommand, AddWorkspaceCommand, DeleteWorkspaceCommand). A workspace is a DetailViewModel that has a CloseCommand.

I found [Josh Smith's MVVM article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) useful for grokking this design.

HTH,
Berryl